# Qt: chicken/egg problem with Initial Size of sub-QWidget

Tags: qt

I have a *.ui definition I'm loading and running. A certain sub-widget there has the rectangle of (x=0,y=88,w=400,h=200). When I instantiate the QWidget class based on the *.ui, and show() it, everything is fine.

I need to be able to get this rectangle BEFORE I show the widget.

When I just instantiate the class, the geometry object always returns (0,0,100,30). Only after I "show()" the widget, I'll get the correct geometry. I may be able to use the sizeHint for this sub-widget, but what about the "hint-X" or "hint-Y"? how do I get to my (x=0,y=88,w=400,h=200) BEFORE showing the widget? This is critical for one of my applications (this is a 3rd party component requirement, it cannot change).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [resize event](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qresizeevent.html) will tell you what you need to know but there are a number of different ways to intercept it, depending on your situation.

If you are dealing with a QWidget subclass of your own, you can override [resizeEvent()](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qwidget.html#resizeEvent). If not, you can install an [event filter](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qobject.html#installEventFilter) on the object.

There are a couple of other options that are variations of these. The important parts of the documentation are [The Event System](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/eventsandfilters.html) and [QCoreApplication::notify](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/latest/qcoreapplication.html#notify)